# In a raffle, $9$ tickets numbered $1$ to $9$ are sold. Two numbers are chosen at random. You hold tickets $1$ to $2$.

Tags: probability, permutations, random-variables, combinations

In a raffle, $9$ tickets numbered $1$ to $9$ are sold. Two numbers are chosen at random. You hold tickets $1$ to $2$. Find the probability that you:

$a)$win at least $1$ prize

$b)$exactly $1$ prize

Honestly I don't know how to start, because there is no criteria given for winning a prize. How do I approach the problem. Can anyone guide or give a hint? How do I start it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "two numbers chosen at random" indicates that two numbers are going to be chosen randomly from $1,2,...9$ by a lottery. You have tickets numbered $1$ and $2$, so if either of those come up in the chosen numbers, you win one prize. If the two chosen numbers are $1$ and $2$, you win both the prizes. Hope its clear enough now.